# getCount() function of 2 ViewPagers are conflicting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have two ViewPagers First have 5 Views (Fragments)  and Second Have 3 Fragments inside a single java file. The problem is when second view shows Fragment 1st then i can only access 3 Fragments of First ViewPager 1-3 and when second View Pager is showing 3rd Fragment then can access only 3-5 fragment means can access only 3 fragment at a time.

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {



    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        //Log.e("Position", position+"");
        if(position==0){
            fragment=new AssetSelectionFragmentWallpaper();
        }
        else{

            fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position+1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

        }



        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof UpdateableFragment) {
            ((UpdateableFragment) object).update(null);

        }
        if(object instanceof AssetSelectionFragmentWallpaper){
            return POSITION_NONE;

        }

        return super.getItemPosition(object);


    }
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter1 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Fragment fragment;
    private Swipe sw;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter1(FragmentManager fm, Swipe s) {
        super(fm);
        this.sw = s;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            fragment = new DummySectionFragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment1.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment1.ARG_OBJECT, position+1);



        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "SETTINGS";
        case 1:
            return "SHOP";
        case 2:
            return "CONTACTS";
        case 3:
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        // don't return POSITION_NONE, avoid fragment recreation.

        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

}
```

Every Object Name is Different and Globally Declared...

I think `getCount()` Function is conflicting to each other.

Please Help to resolve this...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your XML first, if there you find any problem. or
You can fix also by declaring any RONDOM ID like _pager.setId(int);